# Rails: routes generated by hand have different prefix from those created with resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, prefix

I want to create rails routes by hand rather than using the automatic `resource :tasks` (it's just an exercise, I'll go back to the using resources :tasks once I understand this).

I /think/ that I have the right syntax, but the prefixes (path_helpers) generated when I write the routes by hand are wrong. Why, and what am I not doing properly?

Here is my code:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
      root to: 'tasks#index'
      get 'tasks', to: 'tasks#index'
      get 'tasks/:id', to: 'tasks#show'
      get 'tasks/new', to: 'tasks#new'
      post 'tasks', to: 'tasks#create'
      get 'tasks/:id/edit', to: 'tasks#edit'
      patch 'tasks/:id', to: 'tasks#update'
      delete 'tasks/:id', to: 'tasks#destroy'
end
```

Here are the routes & prefixes it creates when I call `rails routes` in my terminal:

```
   Prefix Verb   URI Pattern               Controller#Action
     root GET    /                         tasks#index
    tasks GET    /tasks(.:format)          tasks#index
          GET    /tasks/:id(.:format)      tasks#show
tasks_new GET    /tasks/new(.:format)      tasks#new
          POST   /tasks(.:format)          tasks#create
          GET    /tasks/:id/edit(.:format) tasks#edit
          PATCH  /tasks/:id(.:format)      tasks#update
          DELETE /tasks/:id(.:format)      tasks#destroy
```

Here is what I get when I use `resource :tasks`

```
   Prefix Verb   URI Pattern               Controller#Action
    tasks GET    /tasks(.:format)          tasks#index
          POST   /tasks(.:format)          tasks#create
 new_task GET    /tasks/new(.:format)      tasks#new
edit_task GET    /tasks/:id/edit(.:format) tasks#edit
     task GET    /tasks/:id(.:format)      tasks#show
          PATCH  /tasks/:id(.:format)      tasks#update
          PUT    /tasks/:id(.:format)      tasks#update
          DELETE /tasks/:id(.:format)      tasks#destroy
```

EDIT:

To answer a few of the answers: I know that I can use 'as' to name the prefixes, but I think that I shouldn't have to in this case. 
From what I understand, 'as' is only used in case you want to change the standard prefix to a personalized one, or if you think your routes might change in the future and you don't want to risk to mess with with your helpers. I should still get correct prefixes without using 'as'. 
Here though, the prefix tasks_new with the get method is both linked to the tasks#new and tasks#edit methods, which I don't think is right.

Comment: Just as a little add-on, if you want to keep track of your routes and prefixes during development, you can add this gem: https://rubygems.org/gems/restful_routing

Answer (score 0):

Rails will let you name the routes.  For example:

`get 'tasks/new', to: 'tasks#new', as: :new_task`

Comment: I know that I can use 'as' to name the routes, but I think that I shouldn't have to in this case. 
From what I understand, 'as' is only used in case you want to change the standard prefix to a personalized one, or if you think your routes might change in the future and you don't want to risk to mess with with your helpers. I should still get correct prefixes without using 'as'. 
Here though, the prefix tasks_new with the get method is both linked to the tasks#new and tasks#edit methods, which I don't think is right.

Comment: But you should be using `resources`.  You're expecting rails to parse every get method in case it goes to the new method in the controller. What if you had `get 'tasks/something', to: 'tasks#new'` should that be `new_task_path` or `something_task_path`.  It would add overhead for imo no discernible benefit

Comment: I know. As I said at the start of my question, "it's just an exercise, I'll go back to the using resources :tasks once I understand this". Although it might not be efficient, it should still work, so I'm trying to understand why it doesn't.

Comment: Because rails doesn't parse the get, by the looks of it the default is `"#{controller_name}_#{controller_action}"`

Answer (score 0):

Use **as** for naming the route.
Write the code as following:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
      root 'tasks#index'
      get 'tasks' => 'tasks#index', as: 'task_list'
      get 'tasks/:id' => 'tasks#show', as: 'display_task'
      get 'tasks/new' => 'tasks#new', as: 'task_new'
      post 'tasks' => 'tasks#create', as: 'task_create
      get 'tasks/:id/edit' => 'tasks#edit', as: 'task_edit'
      patch 'tasks/:id', to: 'tasks#update'
      delete 'tasks/:id', to: 'tasks#destroy'
end
```

Comment: I know that I can use 'as' to name the routes, but I think that I shouldn't have to in this case. 
From what I understand, 'as' is only used in case you want to change the standard prefix to a personalized one, or if you think your routes might change in the future and you don't want to risk to mess with with your helpers. I should still get correct prefixes without using 'as'. 
Here though, the prefix tasks_new with the get method is both linked to the tasks#new and tasks#edit methods, which I don't think is right.